# Using std::sort with pointers to integer variables produces unexpected output

Tags: c++, sorting

I decided to compile and run this piece of code (out of curiosity) and the G++ compiler successfully compiled the program. I was expecting to see a compile error or a runtime error, or at least the values of a and b swapped (as 5 > 1), since the `std::sort()` function is being called with two pointers to integers.
(Please note that I know this is not a good practice and I was basically just playing with pointers)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int a{5};
    int b{4};
    int c{1};
    int* aptr = &a;
    int* bptr = &b;
    std::sort(aptr, bptr);
    std::cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

However, upon executing the program, the output I got was this:

```
5 4 1
```

My question is, how did C++ allow this call to the `std::sort()` function? And how did it not end up actually sorting everything between the memory addresses of a and b (potentially including even garbage values in memory)?

I mean, if we tried this with C-style arrays like this (`std::sort(arr, arr+n)`) it would successfully sort the C-style array, because `arr` and `arr+n` are basically just pointers where `n` is the size of the array and `arr` is the pointer to the first element.

(I'm sorry if this question sounds stupid. I'm still learning C++.)

Comment: As long as a C++ program is syntactically valid, the C+ compiler will compile it. However, just because a C++ program compiles without a compilation error doesn't mean that it works correctly, or even makes sense. You've just written in C++ "please shoot me in the foot", and what you wrote is a syntactically valid C++ program.

Comment: What @SamVarshavchik is telling you is that your programme suffers from undefined behaviour; end iterator must be legally reachable from begin iterator; this is not the case because `aptr` and `bptr` do not point to the same array (or the element one past the last thereof). Most likely, your stack is growing top down, so `bptr` has lower address than `aptr`, and you've been lucky (or unlucky, depending on point of view) that your programme didn't crash...

Comment: Another one of those "this program is clearly wrong, why didn't it crash?" questions and the answer is always "you have [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), so **anything** can happen". The compiler could have noticed that the call to `std::sort()` produces UB and just completely optimized it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is ill formed, no diagnostic required.  You passed pointers that do not form a range to a std algorithm.

Any behaviour whatsoever by the program is conforming to the C++ standard.

Compilers optimize around the fact that pointers to unrelated objects are incomparable and their difference is undefined.  A sort here would trip over so much UB the optimizer could eliminate branches like crazy (as any branch with UB can be eliminated and replaced with the alternative (whatever code the alternate branch is a legal result of UB)).

Good C++ coding style thus focuses on avoiding UB and IL-NDR code.

Answer (score -1):

C++ accepts your code as it is syntactically right. But it doesn't work because sort(it1, it2) expects it1 one to be some starting position of an array and it2 to be the ending position of the same array. you have provided two different arrays to the sort function which can yield any of two following situations:

**positionof(it1) < positionof(it2)**: suppose in computer's memory array a and b are stored in the like this- 5(a), -1, -2, 10, 4(b). then the sort function will sort from 5 to 4 resulting in : -2(a),-1,4,5,10(b).

**positionof(it1) > positionof(it2) (your machine's case):** the sort function will do nothing as left_position > right_position.

Comment: `positionof(it1) > positionof(it2) (your machine's case): the sort function will do nothing as left_position > right_position.` thats not true. It is undefined behavior.

Comment: There are no arrays in the posted question.